# why am I getting Authentication user provider [eloquent.multiple] is not defined after upgrading

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to upgrade my laravel project from 5.8 to 8, so I do it step by step so I make sure that everything is working fine, I upgraded from 5 to 6 and everything was working fine, after I upgraded from 6 to 7 I got this error. anyone can help?

**"Authentication user provider [eloquent.multiple] is not defined."**

and here is my config/auth.php

```
 <?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session", "token"
    |
    */

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent", "eloquent.multiple"
    |
    */

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent.multiple',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
            'mapping' => [
                App\Models\User::ADMIN_TYPE => App\Models\Admin::class,
                App\Models\User::USER_TYPE => App\Models\User::class,
            ],
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],

];
```

Answer (score 0):

referencing to this part of your config

```php
    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent.multiple',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
            'mapping' => [
                App\Models\User::ADMIN_TYPE => App\Models\Admin::class,
                App\Models\User::USER_TYPE => App\Models\User::class,
            ],
        ],
```

`eloquent.multiple` seems to be a custom driver. You could check in the git history who added it there, and what he added with it.

[Here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#adding-custom-user-providers) you can find the documentation how a custom driver was registered back in Laravel 5.8.

Without knowing your code, I can't really help any further. But you might investigate if it has to do with Laravels decission to export authentication scaffolding to an external package. Maybe you just have to add `laravel/ui`-package and everything is back to normal. Check the docs here: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/upgrade#authentication-scaffolding

Comment: yeah I've added laravel/ui already while upgrading